# Select rows with the same set regardless of the order

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given:

```
id | a | b | c
---------------
1  | 3 | 8 | 7
2  | 4 | 5 | 6
3  | 0 | 8 | 1
4  | 2 | 4 | 6
5  | 6 | 5 | 4
6  | 9 | 5 | 2
7  | 0 | 1 | 8
```

Like in a lottery, I wanted to select all rows that has the same combination regardless of the order. Expected selection should give me

```
id | a | b | c
---------------
2  | 4 | 5 | 6
5  | 6 | 5 | 4
3  | 0 | 8 | 1
7  | 0 | 1 | 8
```

I tried SELF JOINing the table itself, not sure if it's the right approach. This is postgres

Comment: Why you select id =2 when id=5 has the same numbers? or just select any one? And why you select id 3 and 7 both have same numbers

Comment: this is an existing database and i have a business requirement to get the same combinations

Comment: They are selecting the duplicates. 2/5 are duplicate combinations so they are both selected; as are 3/7.

Comment: what is your rdbms? mysql? postgres? sql server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres has some capabilities that make this work nicely.  In particular, you can order the columns in an array and then count the number of duplicates:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by ar) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   (select array_agg(el order by el)
                    from (values (t.a), (t.b), (t.c)) v(el)
                   ) as ar
            from mytable t 
           ) t
     ) t
where cnt > 1
order by ar;
```

Very importantly:  This works for *exact* matches, even with duplicates.  So, (1, 1, 2) does not match (1, 2, 2).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `exists` for filtering:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.id <> t.id
        and t1.a in (t.a, t.b, t.c)
        and t1.b in (t.a, t.b, t.c)
        and t1.c in (t.a, t.b, t.c)
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=463e4b2603043683086c384f60ce9673)**:

```
id |  a |  b |  c
-: | -: | -: | -:
 5 |  6 |  5 |  4
 7 |  0 |  1 |  8
 2 |  4 |  5 |  6
 3 |  0 |  8 |  1
```

Comment: I think you want EXISTS looks like he want to find duplicates

Comment: And is T1.a T1.b and T1.c not T1.id

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: ah yes you are correct, I edited my answer.

Comment: You want both records so t1.id <> t.id

Comment: @letthefireflieslive . . . This will identify (1, 2, 2) and (1, 1, 2) as the same.  Your question does not specify what to do about duplicates, but I don't think this is a correct answer to the question:  "I want to select all rows that has the same combination regardless of the order."

Answer (score 1):

I was curious how match your desire output puting the match together

Using GMB answer you can add a sort field

**[SQL DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1313af94bef87e052e67e263d266d144)**

```
select t.*, LEAST (t.id, (select t1.id
                          from mytable t1
                          where t1.id <> t.id
                            and t1.a in (t.a, t.b, t.c)
                            and t1.b in (t.a, t.b, t.c)
                            and t1.c in (t.a, t.b, t.c)
                         )
                   ) as sortfield
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.id <> t.id
        and t1.a in (t.a, t.b, t.c)
        and t1.b in (t.a, t.b, t.c)
        and t1.c in (t.a, t.b, t.c)
)
ORDER BY sortfield
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id  a   b   c   sortfield
5   6   5   4   2
2   4   5   6   2
7   0   1   8   3
3   0   8   1   3
```